# How to Implement OAuth Prompt Authentication for Virtual Assistant Bot with Skills

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, botframework

I followed [step-by-step docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-msgraph-auth) to add authentication to a [sample skill](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/tree/master/skills/src/csharp/todoskill/todoskill) as part of a virtual assistant bot created via the [Virtual Assistant Template](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/tree/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp/Sample/VirtualAssistantSample).

I have created an Azure Active Directory V2 app registration for the skill and added an OAuth connection linked to that app in the skill bot in Azure portal. I have also updated OAuthConnections in appsettings.json of the skill.

appsettings.json

```
  "oauthConnections": [
    {
      "name": "calendarconnection",
      "provider": "Azure Active Directory v2"
    }
    . . .
```

But I am stuck on how to implement the OAuth prompt flow for the user to log in to the skill from the virtual assistant, since the virtual assistant template is built in a specific way, i.e. MainDialog inherits from RouterDialog.

```
public class MainDialog : RouterDialog
{
    public MainDialog(
            BotSettings settings,
            BotServices services,
            OnboardingDialog onboardingDialog,
            EscalateDialog escalateDialog,
            CancelDialog cancelDialog,
            List<SkillDialog> skillDialogs,
            IBotTelemetryClient telemetryClient,
            UserState userState)
            : base(nameof(MainDialog), telemetryClient)
    {
        . . .
    }

    . . .

    protected override async Task RouteAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        . . .
    }
    . . .
    protected override async Task<InterruptionAction> OnInterruptDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        . . .
    }
    . . .
```

What would I need to do differently from the code shown in the step-by-step docs in this case?

UPDATE:
I added a new dialog LoginDialog and launched it from OnStartAsync

**MainDialog.cs**

```
        public MainDialog(
            BotSettings settings,
            BotServices services,
            ResponseManager responseManager,
            ConversationState conversationState,
            UserState userState,
            ProactiveState proactiveState,
            CreateEventDialog createEventDialog,
            ChangeEventStatusDialog changeEventStatusDialog,
            TimeRemainingDialog timeRemainingDialog,
            SummaryDialog summaryDialog,
            UpdateEventDialog updateEventDialog,
            ConnectToMeetingDialog connectToMeetingDialog,
            UpcomingEventDialog upcomingEventDialog,
            LoginDialog loginDialog,               // added
            OAuthPrompt oAuthPrompt,               // added
            ConfirmPrompt confirmPrompt,           // added
            IBotTelemetryClient telemetryClient)
            : base(nameof(MainDialog), telemetryClient)
        {
            _settings = settings;
            _services = services;
            . . .

            AddDialog(loginDialog);
            AddDialog(oAuthPrompt);
            AddDialog(confirmPrompt);

        }
        . . .
        protected override async Task OnStartAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(LoginDialog));
            // send a greeting if we're in local mode
            await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(_responseManager.GetResponse(CalendarMainResponses.CalendarWelcomeMessage));
        }
        . . .
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 . . .
     services.AddTransient<LoginDialog>();
     services.AddTransient<OAuthPrompt>();
     services.AddScoped<ConfirmPrompt>(_ => new ConfirmPrompt(nameof(ConfirmPrompt)));
     services.AddScoped<OAuthPrompt>(_ => new OAuthPrompt(nameof(OAuthPrompt), new OAuthPromptSettings { ConnectionName = "calendarconnection", Title = "Sign In" }));
 . . .
}
```

**LoginDialog.cs**

```
public class LoginDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    public LoginDialog() 
        : base(nameof(LoginDialog))
    {
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            PromptStepAsync,
            LoginStepAsync,
            DisplayTokenPhase1Async,
            DisplayTokenPhase2Async

         }));
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

    {

        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);

    }
    . . .
}
```

**The biggest issue here is that I am still being asked to sign in after I already signed in. Note also that the third OAuth prompt is different which is why I get the following error when I click on it.**

Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

Inner error
[image]

[image]

This is where the exception occurs in the code:

**MSGraphCalendarAPI.cs**

```
private async Task<List<Event>> GetMyCalendarViewByTime(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
      . . .
      try
      {
           events = await _graphClient.Me.CalendarView.Request(options).GetAsync();
      }
      catch (ServiceException ex)
      {
           throw GraphClient.HandleGraphAPIException(ex);
      }
      . . .
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post how you configured the oauthConnections in the appsettings.json?

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: The oauthConnections looks fine. Can you post on what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have updated the post on what I have tried.

Comment: The error is returned from the Microsoft Graph API. I would suggest to parse the token and see if there's something wrong with it. Can you try parsing it at https://jwt.ms? In the meanwhile, I will have a look at your updated code and get back on the same.

Comment: I was given the conversation ID "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX|livechat" instead of a JWT token. Why is this?

Comment: When you click on the token message, what does it show up on the JSON tab?

Comment: I added a screenshot of this in the post.

Comment: Can you click on the 'Sign In' button message, then check the JSON tab and let me know what does it show for the [value](https://imgur.com/TDTdgrQ)?

Comment: The value shown is "oauth://calendarconnection&&&XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX|livechat"

Comment: Since the value starts with 'oauth://', it means that somehow it failed to spin up ngrok and you are in the emulated token flow. The emulator is generating a token on its own since there is something wrong with ngrok. How are you trying to run the VA bot?

Comment: I am running the skill directly in the emulator, but I will later be triggering it from the VA after I register the skill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198202/discussion-between-ranusharao-and-chatbote).